# Add hyphen to NGINX rewrite rule

Tags: regex, nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to add a hyphen symbol [-] between ID and slug in my URL, and I'm using a rewrite rule such this:

```
rewrite  ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*-)(.*)/$ /index.php?type=item&item_type=$1&primary_cat=$2&id=$3&slug=$4 last;
```

If I change the "-" like this:

```
rewrite  ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*~)(.*)/$ /index.php?type=item&item_type=$1&primary_cat=$2&id=$3&slug=$4 last;
```

or this:

```
rewrite  ^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)~(.*)/$ /index.php?type=item&item_type=$1&primary_cat=$2&id=$3&slug=$4 last;
```

everything works perfectly!

However, any of my combinations don't work with a hyphen [-] symbol.

I've realized that this is because hyphen is a "technical" symbol in REGEX. But how in such a case I could get the URL like this:

```
https://example.com/../../../35-my-long-slug/
```

where 35 is the page ID and my-long-slug is the slug. And I need a "-" symbol between them, not "+" not "_" not "~". I need exactly the hyphen "-" symbol!

I was trying any variants such as:

```
(.*[\-])(.*)
(.*)[\-](.*)
```

etc.

Comment: You can escape regex symbols with a backslash `\ `. Replace the hyphen with `\-`.

Comment: I've been trying both... doesn't work. It works only when I use any other symbol unless "-"

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Is there an error or is the output wrong? Please give a failed example.

Comment: URL doesn't open with such parameters, which means that the rewrite rule doesn't work. Once I change "-" to any other symbol, everything works fine.

Comment: When I try the regex `^/(.*)/(.*)/(.*?)-(.*)/$` with your example on here https://www.regextester.com/102896 it works just fine. I only added a `?` to only match the id part of the 35-my-long-slug and moved the hyphen out of the group. You don't actually need to escape hyphens outside of character sets (squared brackets).

Comment: "?" that was a missing element in my formula! Thank you, Peter. My issue is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example of:

```
https://example.com/../../../35-my-long-slug/
```

You are missing a capture group and you should make the ID capture lazy so that `.*` stops capturing at the first hyphen instead of the last. In fact, you should make all of the `.*`s lazy so that they don't overstep their boundaries with the explicit capture of `/`:

```
rewrite  ^/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)-(.*?)/$ /index.php?type=item&item_type=$1&primary_cat=$2&id=$4&slug=$5 last;
```

I am not sure how this affects your `$1` through `$3` but the ID should be in `$4` and the slug should be in `$5`